# Using brms for a logistic regression when the outcome is imperfectly defined

Tags: logistic-regression, bayesian, brms

I'm trying to use `brms` package to run a model where my dependent variable Y is an estimate of the latent variable (Disease=0 absent or Disease=1 present with a probability `p`).
I've a dataframe `bd` which contains a dichotomous variable Y (result of a test either positive 1 or negative 0 for assessing the disease status), and 3 covariates (X1 numeric, X2 and X3 as factors)

Y~q #where q is a Bernoulli event and `q` depends on the false positive and false negative fraction of the test.
q­­~ p*Se +(1-p)*(1-Sp) # **true positive and false positive depending on the true probability of disease `p`**

The model I want to finally obtain is on the form:

> logit(p)~ X1 + X2 + X3  **#I want to determine the impacts of my Xi's on the latent variable p**

I used `brms` package with a non linear formula but struggle with specific problems

> bform <- bf(
> Y~q, **#defining my Bernoulli event**

> nlf(q~ Se * p+(1-p) * (1-Sp)),

> nlf(p~inv_logit(X1 + X2 + X3)),
> Se+Sp~1,
> nl=TRUE,
> family=bernoulli("identity"))

**I put some priors on the test sensitivity ans specificity using beta priors but letting default priors for logistic regression coefficients** => bprior

> bprior <- set_prior("beta(4.6, 0.86)", nlpar="Se", lb=0, ub=1)+
> set_prior("beta(77.55, 4.4)", nlpar="Sp", lb=0, ub=1)

**My final model looks like** (using the previously created list `bform` and `bprior` ):

> brm(bform, data=bd, prior=bprior, init="0")

When running the model I only get posteriors from the Se and Sp parameters but I am not able to see any coefficient associated with my covariables X1, X2, X3.
I guess my model has a mistake but I'm not able to see what's happen.
Any help would be **greatly** appreciated!!!

I expected to get output from the line code `p~inv_logit(X1 + X2 + X3))` to be able to determine coefficients associated with this logistic regression (accounting for imperfect dependent variable estimation)